# Error function not returning JSON format

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to pass a JSON error object into my code using the error function in two cases. Once in the email and password check statement and again in the if existingUser statement. I think it's just that time of the night.

```
const User = require('../models/user');

exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    if (!email || !password) {
        return res.err("Please enter in email and password");
    }

    //See if a user with the given email exists
    User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, existingUser) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        //If a user with email does exist, return an Error
        if (existingUser) {
        //the status sets the status of the http code 422 means couldn't process this
            return res.err( 'Email is in use' );
        }
        //If a user with email does NOT exist, create and save user record
        const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: password
        });

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            //Respond to request indicating the user was created
            res.json({ success: true });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are not returning the right status code in your response, you could try this:

Replace:

`return res.err("Please enter in email and password");`

With

`return res.status(422).send({error: "Please enter in email and password"})`

And replace:

`return res.err( 'Email is in use' );`

With:

`return res.status(422).send({ error: "Email is in use" });`

This will send back the required status code in the http response.

Also consider only using single or double quotes in your code for consistency.